# Bootstrap carousel arrows in slider is not working

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, slider, carousel

When I put the slider in the middle of the page the arrows is not working. But if the carousel is in the upper part it's working properly. By the way I just imported the bootstrap plugin of carousel slider and I haven't change anything.

Does anyone encounter this problem?

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
</ol>
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item active">
    <img alt="First slide" src="http://37.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m8tay0JcfG1qa42jro1_1280.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img alt="Second slide" src="http://37.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m8tazfiVYJ1qa42jro1_1280.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img alt="Third slide" src="http://38.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m8tb2rVsD31qa42jro1_1280.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</a>
```

js:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/transition.js"></script>
<script src="js/carousel.js"></script>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Well, you wanted a product filter and this is what I came up with - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3w0qzLzg/6/).

Comment: Or try this: http://jsfiddle.net/x0rp0Lae/7/embedded/result/